# No output for function

Tags: python-2.7

```
def solution(number):
  x = 0
  total = 0
  while x < number:
    if x % 3 == 0 or x % 5 == 0:
      total = total + x
      x = x + 1
  print total
  return total

solution(10)
```

Hello, when I run this code through IDE nothing happens.
What's wrong with it? There are no errors or anything.

Comment: `x = x + 1` is inside the if block so if the condition is false, `x` is never incremented and you get an infinite loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you enter an infinite loop due to x incremental issue.

```
def solution(number):
  x = 0
  total = 0
  while x < number:
    if x % 3 == 0 or x % 5 == 0:
      total = total + x
    x = x + 1
  print total
  return total
```

Just increment x independently from the if condition that may prevent its incremental.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14485416)

Comment: This is the issue and the solution is that he must make sure that x increments out the if condition.

Comment: You should `code` up the actual answer for an answer post. Your current post is a comment about what you *think* should be done, not the answer. See this [meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/163589/292533).

Comment: I have added the edited code, notice that I have answered that question from a smart phone where I do not have the flexibility to code on it.

Comment: While writing code is more difficult on a mobile device, mobile code editing functionality is provided and the answer quality should not suffer.  Thanks for improving!